# Cleaning up angular.forEach / if statements into more concise code?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, foreach

I got the result I wanted - but I am doing it in a way that is just, wow.
I keep finding the right array within an array, and then doing a `foreach` and `if` to find the next correct array. Is there a more sanitary way to do this? My code is below:

```
 angular.forEach($scope.bitrates, function(bitrateset) {
         if(bitrateset.resolution == cam.camera.resolution){
            angular.forEach(bitrateset.stats, function(stat) {
                if(stat.activity == cam.activity){
                    angular.forEach(stat.fps, function(fps) {
                        angular.forEach(fps.range, function(range) {
                        if(range == cam.fps){
                            cam.bitrate = fps.bitrate;
                        }
                        else{
                        }
                    });
                });
                }
         });
         }
    });
```

Comment: Can you attach an example of `bitrates` array, please?

Comment: Could you switch to dict/object instead? Generally much better for when you want to do direct lookups.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with the `bitrates` array @Cherniv http://jsfiddle.net/Dq4j8/